# container div extra margin ie6

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="halfLeft"></div>
        <div class="halfRight"></div>
    </div>
</div>

#container{ width:960px;margin:auto; background-image:url(../img/contentbg.jpg);}
.halfLeft{font: 1.5em BrushcutRegular; background:url(../img/halfbg.png) no-repeat;margin:12px 0px 12px 12px;float:left;width:468px;height:336px;}
.halfRight{font: 1.5em BrushcutRegular; background:url(../img/halfbg.png) no-repeat;margin:12px 12px 12px 0px;float:right;width:468px;height:336px;}
```

For some reason this makes #container add an extra 12px on the left in IE6...

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried removing CSS properties until the problem goes away? Also, it's generally better practice to float both a left and right div left, even though it seems counter intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add some styles to #content:

```
padding: 12px;
overflow: hidden; /* Floating fix for modern browsers */
zoom: 1; /* Floating fix for IE */
```

And remove margin from .halfLeft and .halfRight.

Comment: Notice: I don't know what styles you applied to #content before, so be carefull. If there is a 'width' in #content {}, you should edit its value, for example: #content {width: 960px} should be #content {width: 936px;} because of padding.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: inline;` to both `.halfLeft` and `.halfRight`.

Further info: [The IE5/6 Doubled Float-Margin Bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html)